# Amazon S3 integration on per user basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a web-app where I store user upload files, I am currently using my own S3 account to store the files. The file sizes are getting large so I want to develop a solution where each user can provide me with his S3 bucket keys and all the files that he owns are store in his own s3 bucket.

I need some suggestions with the following ?

1- What should I ask the user to provide me ? S3 bucket keys ? Is bucket name also required ?
2- How can I verify that the provided keys are valid ?
3- What do I need to do to upload/download files from the user's S3 bucket. will normal S3 operations work ?
4- Any examples or documentation you can point me to ?

I am using Ruby on Rails and S3+PaperClip gems to upload files right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user will need to provide you their credentials to and the name of the bucket in a form. The config will happen on the config of the paperclip on the model you using to store images.

You would declare option for your paperclip config

```
def config(options)
    key = options[:key]
    ......
    bucket = options[:bucket]
end
```

and then initialize paperclip with that data.